# How can I get smooth movement in pygame?

Tags: python, loops, oop, module, pygame

How can I make my character move smoothly in pygame? When I create a regular program I seem to be able to get smooth movement by decreasing the velocity (how far the character moves for each step) and decreasing the time delay so that it quickly moves small steps.

The code for that could look something like this (here I just have a simple rectangle moving across the screen.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

x = 400
y = 400
width = 60
height = 60
vel = 2

run = True

while run:
    pygame.time.delay(10)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > vel:
        x -= vel

    if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < 500 - width - vel:
        x += vel

    win.fill((0, 0, 0))
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (x, y, width, height))
    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

However, when I tried to make the game object-oriented I didn't get the character to move smoothly. The code for that looks like this. What am I doing wrong?

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

class player():
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.vel = 2
        self.left = False
        self.right = False

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (man.x, man.y, man.height, man.width))
        if self.left:
            pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (man.x, man.y, man.height, man.width))
        elif self.right:
            pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (man.x, man.y, man.height, man.width))


def re_draw():
    win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))
    man.draw()
    pygame.display.update()


man = player(400, 400, 60, 60)

run = True


while run:
        pygame.time.delay(10)

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and man.x > man.vel:
            man.x -= man.vel
            man.left = True
            man.right = False

        elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and man.x < 500 - man.width - man.vel:
            man.x += man.vel
            man.left = False
            man.right = True

        re_draw()

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: What is it that isn't working when you switch approach? What were you expecting and what happened instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `pygame.time.delay`, you can use `clock.tick`.

```
import pygame

pygame.init()

win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

class player():
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.vel = 2
        self.left = False
        self.right = False

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (man.x, man.y, man.height, man.width))
        if self.left:
            pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (man.x, man.y, man.height, man.width))
        elif self.right:
            pygame.draw.rect(win, (255, 0, 0), (man.x, man.y, man.height, man.width))


def re_draw():

    man.draw()
    pygame.display.update()


man = player(400, 400, 60, 60)

run = True
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while run:

        win.fill((0, 0, 0)) # fill the window with your desired color
        # pygame.time.delay(10) use clock.tick instead

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run = False

        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

        if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and man.x > man.vel:
            man.x -= man.vel
            man.left = True
            man.right = False

        elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and man.x < 500 - man.width - man.vel:
            man.x += man.vel
            man.left = False
            man.right = True

        man.draw() # this might be better

        pygame.display.update()

        clock.tick(60) 

pygame.quit()
```

Hope this helps and welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: `clock.tick(60)` does not increase FPS, quite the opposite! It delays the game so it runs at a *maximum* of 60 frames per second.

Comment: oh my apolliges i will edit it. But i have tested th code and it deos infact run smother like this

Comment: No problem glad i could help :)

Comment: @DenFulaAnkungen I believe that the actual problem with your second approach is that your `re_draw` function has the line `pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))`, which basically reformats the whole display. This is a ***very*** costly function and should only be called when starting the program or when changing the size of the display. In your first approach, you correctly call it just once when the program starts.

Comment: @DenFulaAnkungen Using `clock.tick(60)` is a more standardized and preferred way of capping the FPS, but it does nothing more than delaying your program (and optionally returns how many milliseconds have passed since the last call).

Comment: @TedKleinBergman if there is another way to make the program smoother with it not being so costly and delaying the program I would really appreciate if you posted a solution. Thanks for being so dedicated to helping me.

Comment: @DenFulaAnkungen I can't post an answer as the question is put on hold. But basically, just remove `pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))` from `re_draw` and it should work as expected. The function is more or less only supposed to be called when you want to initialize the display or change the display size.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman thanks! Now I only have ```win.fill((0, 0, 0))```. Working great